# How to determine whether the user has scrolled past the first cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

On iOS, when you append something to the beginning of UITableView's data source, the cell will "animate in" and push the rest of the cells down only if the user is already scrolled to the top.  When the user is scrolled down farther down the list and a new item gets appended to the top, iOS does not automatically move the cells down.

When a new cell comes in from the top, how do I determine between the two?

My use case is that when the user has scrolled down past the iOS point, I can display a "new item above" button for the user to click . (similar to Twitter)

I'm using dynamic height for cells, so hard coding the scrollView by pixel isn't the most ideal way. I'd like to utilize iOS's way to determine it.

Comment: Or you could always scroll the new row into view using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an array available of all visible cells' index paths called `indexPathsForVisibleRows`.  You can access that property and check to see whether or not your first row is one of them, and go from there.  You can also access `visibleCells` property to get the actual UITableViewCells themselves.

Answer (score 0):

How to determine whether the user has scrolled past the first cell: a UITableView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so you can just look at the contentOffset property.

I'm not exactly sure that that's enough to accomplish what you want though. You could also maybe take advantage of the fact that tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath: method only returns a cell if it's visible, and request the first cell. I've never tried implementing something like this before though so there might be a better approach.